# Writing to a file and asking the user for the file name

Tags: python, file, file-io, printing

```
    import sys
    outfile = open( r'/Users/user1/Desktop/myDoc.txt', 'w' ) 
    outfile.write("hello world")
    outfile.close()
```

Two things I am trying to create a program that creates a file, and writes hello world to that file. Right now I have it setup so it will save to my desktop and name the file "myDoc.html". Is it possible for me to right the file name in a way so it saves to any persons desktop and so the program asks the user how they would like to name the file but keeps the .txt file extension?

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
outfile = input('Enter file name: ')
outfile = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'Desktop',outfile)    
with open(outfile +'.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("hello world")
```

Comment: might want to make sure the file does not exist also in case a user overwrites a file by accident.

Comment: @user3527972 I made a small edit in the third line btw. If you copy and paste it now you'll get your desired result :)